# How can I make an enum item have items of another enum?

Tags: java, enums

I have one enum each for month, quarter, and halfyear

```
public enum Month implements TimeInterval {

    // JAN,FEB,MAR... (all with params & constructors)

    // implementation not important
}

public enum Quarter implements TimeInterval {

    // Q1, Q2 ... (all with params & constructors)

    // implementation not important
}

public enum HalfYear implements TimeInterval {

    // HY1, HY2 (all with params & constructors)

    // implementation not important
}
```

and an enum with a function `getIntervalByMonth(int)` which I don't know how to implement.

```
public enum TimeIntervalUnit {

    MONTH(/* params */),

    QUARTER(/* params */),

    HALF_YEAR(/* params */);


    public TimeInterval getIntervalByMonth(int month) {
        // !!! should return the correct TimeInterval, 
        // for example TimeIntervalUnit.QUARTER.getIntervalByMonth(1) 
        // should return Quarter.Q1
    }

    // some other methods
}
```

I often loop over `TimeIntervalUnit.values()`, and inside that loop I want to use the function `getIntervalByMonth(int)`. How can I implement this? Or can this be refactored?

Comment: Seeing the code of the `Month/Quarter/HalfYear` enums would help as there's a few way this can be acheived.

Comment: Unless you really need an enumeration I would go for a simple class that can process this function. The advantage of a class is that you can assign the enumeration to a private variable and check this variable for your `getIntervalByMonth(int month)` method

Comment: @AdrianJandl No, I want to return an item of the enum `Month` or `Quarter` or `HalfYear` from an item of the Enum `TimeIntervalUnit`.

Comment: @bas, what do you mean by a "simple class that can process this function"? Do you mean a helper class, which has a function `static getIntervalByMonth(TimeIntervalUnit, int)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to add method `boolean containsMonth(int month)` to `TimeInterval` interface. This way you can implement `TimeIntervalUnit` as following:

```
public enum TimeIntervalUnit {

    MONTH(Month.values()),

    QUARTER(Quarter.values()),

    HALF_YEAR(HalfYear.values());


    public TimeInterval getIntervalByMonth(int month) {
        for (TimeInterval value : values) {
            if (value.containsMonth(month)) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private final TimeInterval[] values;

    private TimeIntervalUnit(TimeInterval[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    // some other methods
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Funnily enough, I thought of that just a second before you answered. I guess you used thought transmission technology or something.